# Update field value on documents in MongoDb collection

Tags: c#, mongodb

Schema:

```
 /* 0 */
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("4fb6376ef31dfd11c41c7fd0"),
      "Name" : "A",
      "Val" : "#rt45"
    }

    /* 1 */
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("4fb655aff31dfd11c41c7fd1"),
      "Name" : "B",
      "Val" : "#gh46"
    }

    /* 2 */
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("4fb65626f31dfd11c41c7fd2"),
      "Name" : "C",
      "Val" : "#rt67"
    }
```

I have to insert data to "Name" and want to query that it should check if the values of the field "Name"(here it is A,B,C) is present or not if it is there need to skip from insertion 
Hope someone can help on this , I am on the c# driver Please share sample code Thanks in advance.
I have been on this

```
IMongoQuery query = Query.Exists("_id", true);
                var fields = Fields.Include("Name");
                var result = collection.Find(query).SetFields(fields).SetLimit(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Please show what you tried so far.

Comment: Here i want to check the field value on "Name" as the insertion is happening around the DB from data source , value is already present corresponding to "Name"  or not .

Comment: Edit your question and move code from comment to your question

Comment: Here are some relevant questions you need to answer before deciding on a solution.  How often will this process be happening?  How many entries will there be?  What are the chances of inserting a duplicate value if you don't do any checks?  What is the business cost if the same value is in the collection more than once?

Comment: Apology for delayed reply .This process can happen frequently,almost thousand row and each row contains 150 columns and hundred percent chance for duplicate values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call Find first and see if there already is a document with the same Name value, and then only call Insert if Find returned nothing. This would not be safe if multiple processes or threads were doing the same thing though.

Another way is to create a unique index on Name and just do the Insert. The Insert will then fail if another document already exists with the same Name value.

Answer (score 0):

[FindAndModify](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command) is a way in MongoDB to query for and Update in one go.

Another way is to just user Update

```
Collection.Update(Query. ..., Update.Set())
```

The second one can, if all information for a new post exists also create a post if it is not found by the query.

If you try to write a step by step example of what you are trying to do (in plain English) I might be able to write an example for C#.

Comment: A dictionary contains the data to insert, calling this method public void InsertData(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)  , while inserting there should be a condition , if data from dictionary is already exist in the DB then update.